# How do you set the useCatalog feature on SAXParserFactory?

Tags: java, xml, sax

Edit: Resolved by removing the xercesImpl jar from build.gradle.

I'm attempting to set the useCatalog feature on a `SAXParserFactory` instance. In my testing I'm getting back

`SAXNotRecognizedException: Feature 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/useCatalog' is not recognized.`

What is the proper way to set the useCatalog feature of a `SAXParserFactory`?

I'm also attempting to set the `CATALOG_FILE` property on the `SAXParser` but my testing returns

`SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'javax.xml.catalog.files' is not recognized.`

What is the proper way to set the catalog property on a `SAXParser`?

My sample code follows the JavaDoc example provided for `XMLConstants.USE_CATALOG`.

```
private static final String CATALOG_FILE = CatalogFeatures.Feature.FILES.getPropertyName();
private static final String CATALOG_PREFER = CatalogFeatures.Feature.PREFER.getPropertyName();

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
spf.setXIncludeAware(true);
spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.USE_CATALOG, true);
SAXParser parser = spf.newSAXParser();

if (catalogURIs.size() > 0) {
    List<URI> catalogUriList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String uriString : catalogURIs) {
        catalogUriList.add(URI.create(uriString));
    }

    CatalogResolver resolver =
            CatalogManager.catalogResolver(CatalogFeatures.defaults(),
            catalogUriList.toArray(new URI[catalogUriList.size()]));
    parser.setProperty(CATALOG_FILE, resolver);
    parser.setProperty(CATALOG_PREFER, "system");
}
```

Comment: Resolved by removing the xercesImpl jar from build.gradle.